# How can I run an executable .jar file in an R script?

Tags: java, r, jar, executable

I am working on a relatively large data analytics project in which an R script I wrote is the primary executable, calling all other bits of code. I can't figure out how to call an executable .jar from my R script, however and I haven't seen this question posted elsewhere... is this a possibility?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `rJava` to create an instance of your java Object. Then you call its methods ..

```
library(rJava)
.jinit(PATH_TO_YOUR_JAR) # this starts the JVM
jobject <- .jnew("yourJavaClass")  ## call the constructor
.jcall(jobject ,"I",method="YOUR_METHOD") ## call a method
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
system("path/to/file.jar")
```